# How to specify animation delay and timing-function with Element.animate()?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Say I have something like

```
notificationEl.current.animate([{ opacity: 0 }, { marginTop: marginTop }], {
   duration: 1000,
});
```

but I want I don't want it to start immediately. How can I specify a delay? I've tried looking up all the options that are available as the second argument, but I can't find it on MDN.

Additionally, is there a way to specify %s or is Element.animate() reserved for simple from/to?

I need to use Element.getBoundingClientRect() to move elements the right amount of space since the size of the elements varies. As such, I can't just use keyframes in my CSS. I've never tried to animate something inline, so any help/pointers would be appreciated.

I've already tried to use "delay" as an option, but got an error saying it's invalid. Same goes for timing-function. I want to use ease-out but not sure how to do that using Element.animate().

Is there a better way of achieving a variable margin-top for an animation than using Element.animate() or is that the right choice for what I'm going for?

Thanks.

Comment: For calling a function after some delay, how about `setTimeout`?

Comment: @kiner_shah I thought about it, but decided against it. I'll try it out and see though. What about timing-function? How can I specify, "ease", "ease-in-out", etc.

Comment: You can use `animationTimingFunction` and set appropriate value to it. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animationtimingfunction.asp

Comment: @kiner_shah I remember why I didn't use setTimeout. For some reason it causes my element to blink before exiting. Is there an alternative to Element.animate() that's closer to the CSS way you would declare a keyframe?